# XML Tag Name includes parent class ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rest, xml-serialization

I built an XML from the following class

```
public class Person
{
    public string IDENTITY { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }    

public class Exam[] Exams;
    public class Exam
    {
        public string Name
        public int Pass_Score 
        public int Score 
        public string Grade 

    }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

it generated a file like this:

```
<Person>
    <Name>Jimmy</Name>
    <Age>13</Age>
<Exams>
    <Person.Exam >
        <Name>Math</Name>
        <Pass_Score>70</Pass_Score>
        <Score>75</Score>
        <Grade>C</Grade>
    </Person.Exam>
<Exams>
    <Data>21AUG</Date>
</Person>
```

I have an issue with the tag `<Person.Exam>`
How can I remove it or change the name of it?

Comment: Try moving your class definition for `Exam` outside of the class definition for `Person` -- currently you have `Exam` nested within `Person`.

Comment: I want it to be nested, is there any harm in it?

Comment: Oh Awesome, Your Suggestion solved that you David.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nested classes especially when you fully intend to do it.  I just figured that the nesting had something do with `Person.Exam` references you were seeing in the XML tags.  Glad that worked.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  #SOReadyToHelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer like David Tansey said i have to move the class outside.

```
public class Person
{
    public string IDENTITY { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }    

    public  Exam[] Exams;

    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Exam
    {
        public string Name
        public int Pass_Score 
        public int Score 
        public string Grade 

    }
```